# php wrong utf8 characters from mysql using Twig

Tags: activerecord, utf-8, twig

Im doing some webapp on php, im using my own MVC pattern, including Activerecord, and Twig templates.

So i have some problems with charset, there is some details about my encoding.

- Im using polish characters
- Mysql encoding is set to utf8_unicode_ci (i tried urf8_general_ci)
- Twig template have standard html-5 header with utf8 encoding
- Im not sure about files encoding (using netbeans), but sublime text 2 console on view.encoding() says: u'Undefined', i dont try to change it yet.

Problem description:

When im using polish characters like ółąćź in Twig template file - everything looks good, there is no problem. I tried to use:

```
echo $twig->render('hello.tpl', array('locations'=>"óóśąłłąś"));
```

And in this case is no problem too.

But when I get my data from database the polish characters are like "�"
I tried to get data by structural php mysql call, and by activerecord - ex. Model::all().

It allways have problems with characters from database in Twig template.
And yes, i set my active record config like: dbname?charset=utf8

Answer (score 0):

The answer is funny.

I tried again to do it structural and i used this query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $dbLink);
```

It works, all characters are visible now.
On activerecord the problem still apears, so i updated activerecord to nigtly build, and everything works now !

Comment: You should be using pdo or mysqli, mysql is removed from recent php versions.